# d3.js geoGraticule doesn't follow the sphere shape

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add standard geoGraticule lines to my globe, which spins and has ripple effects. I've gone wrong somewhere but can't get to the bottom of it: [live demo](https://codepen.io/mikechalmers/pen/GRMLBaX?editors=1000)

The meridian lines seem to create a sort of diamond shape, rather than curving around the whole sphere.

How can I change my code so the graticule is spherical?

```
// margin calculations
        const margin = {top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 0};
        const width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            const config = {
                speed: 0.005,
                verticalTilt: -30,
                horizontalTilt: 0
            }


        // add an SVG to the body and a g group
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        var g = svg.append("g");

        // draw a globe I guess
        d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json", (error, world) => {
            // draw the land using TOPOJSON package
            var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

            // d3 3d globe projection
            var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
                .fitSize([width, height], land)
                .clipAngle(90)
                .precision(0)
                .scale(200);
            
            // create projection of earth sphere
            var path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection);
            
            // load the ripple circle
            var geoCircle = d3.geoCircle();

            // load the meridian lines
            var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();
            
            // draw a grey circle to look like water
            var ocean = g.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "ocean")
                .attr("cx", width / 2)
                .attr("cy", height / 2)
                .attr("r", height / 2);
            
            // draw countries
            var earth = g.append("path")
                .datum(land)
                .attr("d", path);

            // draw graticules
            var lines = g.append("path")
                .datum(graticule)
                .attr("class", "graticule")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("fill-opacity", 0)
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-opacity", 0.7);
            
            // list of locations - reverse the lat / long numbers!
            var locale = [
                [37.5999, 14.0153],
                [10.1278, 50.5074],
                [0.1278, 51.5074],
                [25.653906, 4.453784],
                [0, -10],
                [151.2012775, -33.8844644]
            ];

            // draw the circles
            function drawMarkers() {
                for (var i = 0; i < locale.length; i++) {
                    // console.log("location " + (i+1) + ": " + locale[i]);
                    center = locale[i];
                    var circ = g.append("path")
                        .datum({endAngle: 0})
                        .attr("class", "geoCircle")
                        .attr("fill", "#000")
                        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
                        .attr("d", d => path(geoCircle.center(center).radius(1)()));
                }
            }

            // draw the ripples
            setInterval(() => {
                for (var i = 0; i < locale.length; i++) {
                center = locale[i];
                var circ = g.append("path")
                    .datum({endAngle: 0})
                    .attr("class", "ripple ripple" + i)
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("d", d => path(geoCircle.center(center).radius(2)()))
                    .transition()
                    .delay(0)
                    .duration(2800)
                    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                    .attr("opacity", 0)
                    .attrTween("d", geoCircleTween(12, center))
                    .remove();

                function geoCircleTween(newAngle, loca) {
                    return function(d) {
                        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
                        return function(t) {
                            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                            return path(geoCircle.center(loca).radius(d.endAngle)());
                        };
                    };
                } 
            }
            }, 500)

            function enableRotation() {
                d3.timer(function (elapsed) {
                    projection.rotate([config.speed * elapsed - 120, config.verticalTilt, config.horizontalTilt]);
                    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
                    drawMarkers();
                });
            }  
            enableRotation();
            
        });
```

Comment: Up your precision value - a value of 1 looked good to me.

Comment: Oh that's it, thank you - 1 works perfectly.